Linux 32bit GDB debugging
Does anyone know of a 32bit version of the ddd (visual gdb) app?
I am trying to debug a 32 bit app in a 32bit schroot on Ubuntu Linux 22.04 x64 platform.
or as an alternative another way to debug x32 linux apps.
Thanks.
There only seem to be x64 versions of ddd on their website.

64-bit GDB and DDD should have no problem debugging 32-bit ix86 or x32 app. Did you try it?
